# How to do an insert only if certain textboxes are not left blank

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a function that is run on a submit button Onclick that is writing correctly to the table I need.  However within this function I am  calling a public sub "Insert Spouse(intscope)".  The issue I am having is trying to keep this Insert from happening if certain textboxes are left blank.
If I leave the textboxes blank I get an error message saying that the input string was not in correct format. I would like for it to skip this insert entirely if those specific textboxes contain no data.

```
  Public Function CreateRecord()
    Dim intScope As Integer
    Dim dbAddEmployee As New SqlCommand("Insert into mca_DEPDBEmployee (EmpID, FName, LName, SSN, Department, Spousebx) values (@EmpID, @FName, @LName, @SSN, @Department, @Spousebx); Select Scope_Identity()", dbGPconn)

    Dim prmEmpID As New SqlParameter("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Decimal)
    prmEmpID.Value = txtEmpID.Text
    dbAddEmployee.Parameters.Add(prmEmpID)

    Dim prmFName As New SqlParameter("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
    prmFName.Value = txtFName.Text
    dbAddEmployee.Parameters.Add(prmFName)

    Dim prmLName As New SqlParameter("@LName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
    prmLName.Value = txtLName.Text
    dbAddEmployee.Parameters.Add(prmLName)

    Dim prmSSN As New SqlParameter("@SSN", SqlDbType.Int)
    prmSSN.Value = txtEmpSSN.Text
    dbAddEmployee.Parameters.Add(prmSSN)

    Dim prmDepartment As New SqlParameter("@Department", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
    prmDepartment.Value = ddlDept.SelectedItem.Text
    dbAddEmployee.Parameters.Add(prmDepartment)

    Dim prmSpouse As New SqlParameter("@Spousebx", SqlDbType.Bit, 1)
    If rblSelectSpouse.SelectedValue = 1 Then
        prmSpouse.Value = 1
    Else
        prmSpouse.Value = 0
    End If
    dbAddEmployee.Parameters.Add(prmSpouse)

    dbGPconn.Open()
    intScope = dbAddEmployee.ExecuteScalar()
    dbGPconn.Close()

    AddDependents(intScope)
    InsertSpouse(intScope)

    Return intScope
End Function

Public Sub InsertSpouse(ByVal intscope As Integer)

    If txtSpouseNm.Text <> "" And txtSpouseDept.Text <> "" Then
        Dim dbInsertSpouse As New SqlCommand("Insert into mca_DEPDBSpouse ( EmpTableID, EmpID, Name, Department, SpEmpID) Values (@EmpTableID, @EmpID, @Name, @Department, @SpEmpID)", dbGPconn)

        Dim prmEmpTableID As New SqlParameter("@EmpTableID", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18)
        prmEmpTableID.Value = intscope
        dbInsertSpouse.Parameters.Add(prmEmpTableID)

        Dim prmEmpID As New SqlParameter("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18)
        prmEmpID.Value = txtEmpID.Text
        dbInsertSpouse.Parameters.Add(prmEmpID)

        Dim prmName As New SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        prmName.Value = txtSpouseNm.Text
        If txtSpouseNm.Text = "" Then prmName.Value = DBNull.Value
        dbInsertSpouse.Parameters.Add(prmName)

        Dim prmDepartment As New SqlParameter("@Department", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        prmDepartment.Value = txtSpouseDept.Text
        If txtSpouseDept.Text = "" Then prmDepartment.Value = DBNull.Value
        dbInsertSpouse.Parameters.Add(prmDepartment)

        Dim prmSpEmpID As New SqlParameter("@SpEmpID", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18)
        prmSpEmpID.Value = txtSpouseEmpID.Text
        If txtSpouseEmpID.Text = "" Then prmSpEmpID.Value = DBNull.Value
        dbInsertSpouse.Parameters.Add(prmSpEmpID)

        dbGPconn.Open()
        dbInsertSpouse.ExecuteScalar()
        dbGPconn.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: _if string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) Then_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only care about these fields

- txtSpouseNm

  txtSpouseDept

  txtEmpID

  txtSpouseEmpID

```
if String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSpouseNm.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSpouseDept.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmpID.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSpouseEmpID.Text) Then
'Something is missing
else
'everything filled out, do your thing
end if
```

Comment: hey Thank you! once I added the else and included each text box it went through fine!